Editing text: How do I turn a single path into a criss-cross stroke in Illustrator?
I can't seem to find a way to turn the single path in the middle of my letters into a scribble, crisscross, multi line stroke like in the orange image, where you get 3 or 4 strokes that converge. Any idea how to do that without manually drawing every single line, so I can get a consistent look across all my letters, no matter the shape? Thank you.

PS: I'm using Adobe Illustrator but I can use Inkscape if need be.

Try Art Brush in Illustrator or Pattern along Path in Inkscape. Ask more if you find they are useless for your purposes.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Are the letters already constructed from single paths?  If not, then there's probably nothing that will do this automatically if that is what you are asking.  There is a method called centre-line tracing, but it's not perfect and results will vary depending on the letter forms, whether they're simple or complex, and you'd need a raster image to trace.  If you already have the centre lines, then you could create an artbrush in Illustrator and apply it to a path.
